# Existing Gradle Project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I want to Import my Existing Gradle projects into Eclipse which i have checked out from SVN into my local directories. The Projects contains the code on two Branches. I have tried using Importing Existing gradle project Option but after import i am getting No Build Path errors when i am trying to use Eclipse see call hierarchy and other functionalities. I don't necessarily want to build the project from eclipse i just want to edit the code in eclipse and want changes to reflect in the local ,from where i can build manually.

Can you please direct me to some link or provide steps to achieve this?

Comment: FYI..Currently i Am trying to import from local but i am using a different workspace location than my code location and i am not selecting copy to workspace option.

Comment: is using eclipse mandatory or any other IDE is also fine?

Comment: yeah i need to import into eclipse only

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps for importing gradle projects in Eclipse and another IDE Intellij

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-project-by-importing-existing-sources.html
- https://steffenschaefer.github.io/gwt-gradle-plugin/doc/latest/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gradle eclipse plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide) to create a eclipse project file.

First apply the plugin in your `build.gradle` as below :

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

Then use below command to generate the eclipse project file as below:

```
gradle  eclipse
```

Then import this project using eclipse's import project feature.

Comment: this will require me to add this in all the build.gradle files for all modules..is there any other way to achieve it apart from doing it manually